# How to INSERT using a SELECT in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, hql

I need to implement the following request in hibernate:

```
insert into my_table(....,max_column)
values(...,(select max(id) from special_table where ....))
```

How to do that in hibernate, using annotations? special_table may be not a child or dependency of my_table, just a subselect.

Comment: have made relationships in between these tables ?

Comment: Thank you, but no, desirable to make this select with no relationships.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... feature](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_hql_syntax_for_insert):

```
int updateCount = session.createQuery("""
    insert into MyEntity(
        ...,
        max_column
    ) 
    select 
        ..., 
        max(id) 
    from SpecialEntity 
    """)
.executeUpdate();
```