# HQL auto increment INSERT - SELECT : "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Tags: mysql, hibernate, select, hql, sql-insert

I want to ask. i'm using Hibernate

[how-to-write-hql-insert-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635715/how-to-insert-using-a-select-in-hibernate)
because of hibernate can't use insert - value, i should use insert - select. but i don't know how to put auto increment value.

i try to make new DB from
[SQL AUTO INCREMENT Field](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
Personid AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Age int
```

);

I try to put a code like this, but it show me an Error

```
mysql> insert into Persons (Personid,LastName,FirstName,Age)select ('2','Morgen','Lars','12');
```

or

```
mysql> insert into Persons (LastName,FirstName,Age)select ('Morgen','Lars','12');
```

ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select clause of an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` should not be placed in parentheses:

```
INSERT INTO Persons (Personid, LastName, FirstName, Age)
SELECT '2', 'Morgen', 'Lars', '12';
```

While your problem borders on being a typo, it is understandable since `INSERT` with values clause *does* use tuples:

```
INSERT INTO Persons (Personid, LastName, FirstName, Age)
VALUES
    ('2', 'Morgen', 'Lars', '12');
```